# about len str with special characters

Tags: python, unicode

Some special character like '', in Python it's as a character.

```
>>> s = ''
>>> len(s)
3
>>> s[:1]
''
```

but when I put it in Atom, it's as 2 character 
[image]

In addition in java it is also as 2 character

```
jshell> String s = ""
s ==> ""

jshell> s.length()
$4 ==> 6
```

but in terminal it is as one character

```
➜  ~ echo -n '' | wc -m
       3
```

So how to let Python consistent with Atom?

Background:

I want to write some text into excel, but some text is so large and excel cell has a limit: maximum 32767 characters, so I have to restrict text length, e.g. text[:32767] but I found even in this case still cannot open the generated excel, because if there are special characters in the text, its length is actually more than 32767.

Comment: Where do you have info it has length 2?

Comment: Java and Atom..

Comment: @gonczor: He's saying in Java and Atom each emoji character has a length of 2. In Atom, you can see that from the column number after the highlight (6), and Java returns a length of 6 for 3 of these.

Comment: With `len(s.encode('utf-8'))` you can get the number of bytes neccessary to represent `s` in UTF-8 (the encoding your editor is using).

Comment: @Wombatz but the value is 12 `len(s.encode('utf-8')) = 12` I want to get is 2

Comment: OK. I get it now. Looks more like a bug that needs to be reported to atom creators. I do not see it addressed on github.

Comment: "So how to let Python consistent with Atom?" I prefer to think of this as "Well, Python got it right, so how to get Atom be consistent with that?"

Comment: If your end target is Excel, understanding how Excel determines the length of a "character" is what matters here. Since Microsoft are pretty much stuck in UTF-16 my guess is theirs is going to be like Java, but really, check if you can find an actual specification for Excel format, rather than bringing in anecdotal evidence from platforms you don't specifically target.

Comment: this `excell` issue,  so need `byte` size `binascii.hexlify(string)[:32767*2]` because : excell limit `32768, ASCII, 0 to 255,single Byte`

Comment: Especially with emoji there's a lot of them which consist of multiple code points, eg. [country flags](https://emojipedia.org/flags/) (2 code points) and [families ‍‍‍ ](https://emojipedia.org/family-man-woman-girl-boy/) (this particular one consists of 7 code points).

Comment: @roeland Wow, I didn't know that! However, it's probably not the case here, since we would expect the reported lengths to be greater for both Python (which counts codepoints) and Java (which counts UTF-16 words).

Comment: I have written some more about multi code point characters as in @roeland’s comment on https://medium.com/@alvinlindstam/unicode-text-lengt-python-vs-elixir-2d528b801d53

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java an Python have a different definition of a string's length.

- For python it is the number of *Unicode code points*
- For Java it is the number of 16 bits *Unicode code units*.

Characters greater than U+FFFF (like most emojis) need two code units for each code point, one high-surrogate, followed by one low surrogate.

This is not directly related to encoding but because Java and the Unicode specification were originally limited to the U+0000 to U+FFFF range (now called the Basic Multilingual Plane, or BMP). See [Unicode Character Representations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, Now my way is just remove these special characters, please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to compute the length that Java or Atom will use, encode the string in UTF-16LE (or UTF-16BE) and divide by two to get the number of 16-bit code units required.

```
>>> s = ''  # Python 3.6
>>> len(s)
3
>>> len(s.encode('utf-16le'))//2
6
>>> s = 'abc123'
>>> len(s)
7
>>> len(s.encode('utf-16le'))//2
8
```

Or go back to a Python before Python 3.3, which was as broken as Java and Atom...

```
>>> s = u''  # Python 2.7
>>> s
u'\U0001f44d'
>>> len(s)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

So as you can see below, Python and Java have different interpretations of the source code for this specific character:

```
Java/C++ = "\uD83D\uDC4D"
Python = u"\U0001F44D"
```

The best way to deal with this in both respects is converting them in the specific lanaguage to a unique identifier, like :+1: or finding the unique code for them that both languages understand.

Comment: Thanks! but I want to know how to get these unicode info in python and java? Is there some function could directly output these info

Comment: Thanks, now my way is just remove these special characters, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Now in order to generate excel correctly I take the following method:

1.text = text[:32767]

2.than remove the special characters in the text

```
def filter_invalid_str(text):
    try:
        # UCS-4
        highpoints = re.compile(u'[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]')
    except re.error:
        # UCS-2
        highpoints = re.compile(u'[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]')
    return highpoints.sub(u'', text)
```